# Print values from file or pointer in C with openGL

Tags: c, function, opengl, pointers

I need to print 2 vector in openGL but I cannot sent a pointer with the function `glutDisplayFunc`.

`glutDisplayFunc(graphfunct)` I have this once the window is created but I need send the 2 pointers with the address of vector to set the coordinates.

Comment: This is very vague description. Please work on making your question more specific. What do you have and what do you want to get from it in result? *maybe a screenshot or a pic needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters to the function you register with `glutDisplayFunc`. You must use a globally-accessible variable instead.